# How to handle expected alert in nightwatch-cucumber

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

In my `nightwatch.conf.js` I have mentioned the `"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"accept"`.

But I have a scenario where I have to check the alert flow too, like so

```
When I refresh the page
Then I dismiss the alert
```

But when I try to execute the code, the alert is accepted by default and the test fails. I verified this by removing the `"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"accept"`, and the scenario works correctly. Is there any way to programmatically set the `unexpectedAlertBehaviour` value or set the alert as expected? I need the option `"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"accept"` since there are other flows that run based on this